# Vaadin 23.3 close tooltip by clicking on the text

Tags: tooltip, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

I'm upgraded to Vaadin 23.3 Preview because of `Tooltip` component. Works and looks great. Only one question - I use the tooltip as a toggletip. I added an icon to my textfield and manually open tooltip by clicking it. In order to close the tooltip, I have to click the icon one more time.  Is it possible somehow to close the tooltip by clicking the tooltip text also?

Comment: Have you looked at this addon https://vaadin.com/directory/component/tooltips4vaadin ? I think this will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not supported, as the Tooltip feature is not intended to be used for anything interactive. As the [docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/tooltip) say:

> Tooltips only support plain text content. They aren’t focusable and
> can’t contain interactive elements.

Due to technical (and especially accessibility) reasons, interactive popups like that need a different implementation. There are some vague plans to add such a feature to the Vaadin platform in the future, however.

One component in the Vaadin's Directory that can be considered better suited for the task is [Popup](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/popup).